# Visual Studio 2019: Intellisense does not recognize assemblies as referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, .net-assembly

I am encountering an annoying error. We have a solution that roughly consists of about 50 separate projects all being built and referenced to main project as dlls. In Visual Studio 2017 all is fine, no Intellisense errors, project builds and no errors are encountered.

Visual Studio 2019 displays missing assembly references eventhough I can successfully build and run the project:

[image]

**What I have tried to overcome the error:**

- Cleaned and rebuilt the solution
- Removed bin and obj folder of ALL projects as well as the hidden .vs folder in the solution - Built again: Same errors
- Updated to newest Visual Studio version
- Repaired Visual Studio and reinstalled ReSharper

I had no success with all of those steps. Does anyone have an idea on what else I could try?

Comment: Were those projects added as DLL or as an actual project and then referenced?

Comment: Project and then referenced

Comment: When compiling, all projects are built and then used as dll´s in main project

Comment: Try: check framework versions, extension updates. Any build messages?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. See my answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution for my problem. This [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/505489/cannot-navigate-to-the-symbol-under-the-caret-3.html?childToView=531679#comment-531679) and Andrei Romans answer helped. Basically it says:

> Go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> Uncheck "Allow parallel project initialization"

Then close the solution, restart it and finally rebuild the project. That worked for me - no more errors :-)

**EDIT:**

When branching and checking out the error persisted. What I did then is to check the usings that wheren´t recognized and un- and reloading the corresponding project. Currently my issues are resolved by this step.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. this resolved my issue as well!